# Default landing tab for case pagelayout in sf1/mobile

Tags: salesforce1-app, case

In SF1 when i view a case by default its landing on feed tab , i need to make the detail tab as landing tab . But for other objects i am not facing this issue .

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any official documentation on this but, i think this is not possible.There is an idea for this functionality though.We would like the ability to switch the position of the tabs, so that the Details tab is first.

IDEA

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l6E9AAI

Thanks

Diksha Goel